# Using subviews in scrollerview iPhone

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am trying to add uipickerview in uiscrollview, but it is not being shown properly, just a black square.

Further, I have to add 1 more uipickerview, some labels and some buttons.

The code I am using is as under:

```
-(void)loadView {

    [super loadView];

    UIPickerView *pView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 280, 165)];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]];
    scroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    scroller.pagingEnabled = YES;
    NSInteger numberOfViews = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
        CGFloat yOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.height;
        UIView *awesomeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(yOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
       // awesomeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5/i green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1];
        [scroller addSubview:awesomeView];
        [scroller addSubview:pView];

    }
    scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width , self.view.frame.size.height * numberOfViews);
    [self.view addSubview:scroller];

}
```

what can be the issue?

Comment: Is the app actually starting? Because as far as I remember, calling self.view from -loadView starts an infiniteLoop. Try using `self.view = scroller;` instead.

Comment: yes, application is starting properyl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you putting data in the picker view? I mean, if you just put the picker view without data on it you are not going to see anything on it.

You need to add the delegate and the datasource and put some data in your picker!

```
pView.delegate = self;
pView.datasource = self;
```

and then you have to implemente at least:

```
numberOfComponentsInPickerView:
numberOfRowsInComponent: 
titleForRow:
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are implementing uipickerviewdelegate methods. its normal that it will show just the black square because your pickerview cant find the data and thus does not display anything.

Answer (score -1):

```
UIPickerView *pView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 280, 165)];
```

Change height to `216` .. **UIPickerView has fixed height of 216** ..only.. you can't change it..

Comment: I have already tried that, we can modify the height of picker view.